# Ionic 2 card image not resizing to fit inside card when using ion-img with virtualScroll

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am using virtual scroll to output a big list of cards. Here is my code:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { TowersModel } from '../../app/models/towers-model';
import { TowerPage } from '../tower/tower';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-towers',
  templateUrl: 'towers.html'
})
export class TowersPage {

      towers: any;

    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController){ 

      this.towers = [];
      for(let i = 1; i < 2000; i++){
        this.towers.push({
          "name" : "Tower "+i,
          "image" : "http://st.motortrend.com/uploads/sites/10/2015/09/2013-Ferrari-458-Italia-Front-Three-Quarters-View.jpg"
        });
      }
    }

    viewTower(){
      this.navCtrl.push(TowerPage);
    }
}
```

Template:

```
<ion-header>
    <ion-navbar>
        <ion-title>Towers</ion-title>
    </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
    <ion-content>

        <ion-list [virtualScroll]="towers">

          <div *virtualItem="let tower">
            <ion-card>
              <ion-img [src]="tower.image" [width]="2048" [height]="1360"></ion-img>
              <ion-card-content>
                <ion-card-title>{{tower.name}}</ion-card-title>
                <p>Lorem ipsu sum dolor amor sit amet</p>
              </ion-card-content>
            </ion-card>
            </div>

        </ion-list>

    </ion-content>
</ion-content>
```

I have no external css being applied to this page other than the standard ionic framework stuff.

If I use a regular img tag instead of ion-img then the image shrinks down automatically to fit entirely inside the width of the card whilst maintaining the same aspect ratio. When I use ion-img though the image doesn't shrink down to fit inside the card at all and is rendered at original size and so it's massive and doesn't display correctly. How do I get it to fit nicely within the card?

Comment: Perhaps a width 80% and margin 0 auto;

Answer (score 0):

Ionic providers a small set of [helpers](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/theming/css-utilities/). By default when using the `ion-img` tag ionic applies margin to the image depending on the image ratio and its wrapper component.

So if i am not mistaken you can add either `no-margin` or `no-padding` to the image tag to remove the spaced added by default

```
<ion-img [src]="tower.image" [width]="2048" [height]="1360" no-padding no-margin>
</ion-img>
```